# Visual Studio return to previous project build

Tags: visual-studio

Without version control and `ctrl + z`, is there a way to roll back to a previous build in VS2022?

`Ctrl` + `z` won't work since I've closed the VS ( but did not shut down the pc, if that has any matter in that ).

`properties` -> `previous versions` isn't working as well.

Comment: If there is some reason not to use version control, you can create zip archive snapshots of your project.  Close the solution before making the snapshot, and for native code delete the sub-folders that contain the OBJ files to save space.

Comment: If you don't have a backup of your previous state lying around, probably not.

Comment: You can always copy the source files into a new folder and create a new project

Comment: @DaveS As i understand the question, the damage is already done, ie the project is in a state, where it doesn't work correctly anymore and OP is trying undo the changes that caused this ...

Comment: the thing is, I took the original project, copied it and inserted it into a new folder.
When opened the copied project, I didn't notice, that VS has opened for me the original project ( don't ask me how, I'm clueless ), and so happened, that I've changed the code for both projects, the original one and the copy

Comment: if there is a way, that I could use to restore the second folder using `win` + `v` would be nice